# Динамическое количество параметров запроса в БД Java JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, crud

сама задача состоит в том что есть некий реквест с динамическим кол-вом параметров (`/search?param=1&param=2&param=3.....`)
ловлю это все через

```
@RequestParam(value = "param", required = false) List<Integer> paramList)
```

как мне построить запрос к БД через JPA, в котором должно быть динамическое количество AND в WHERE (допустим `select * from t WHERE i.column=q AND i.column=w ....` )?
под запросом через JPA имею ввиду

```
@Query("select....)
public List<Object> findAllBy(@Param);
```

я использую CrudRepository\JPARepository с хибернейтом

Comment: можете воспользоваться `Restrictions` и `Criterion` hibernate'a, в цикле добавлять новый `Restriction` к `Criterion`

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно в указанном случае можно воспользоваться конструкций `in`. Т.е.

```
@Query("select o from Obj o where o.col in (:list)")
public List<Object> findAllBy(@Param("list") List<Object> list);
```

Единственное учти, что входной `List` должен быть не пустой.